# Logs (Text) in ADF for stored procedure activity

Tags: logging, azure-data-factory

I'm doing some sample stored procedure activity in Azure Data factory. I need to create a logging for my ADF solution. I know we can implement the logging with the help of some custom Activity. But is there is any other options(even any other build in Services in Azure) which I can use? And how to implement to my solution without going to custom .NET activity?

If the logging can be possible with in a text file. It will be more useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short **no**, you can't.

Like you mention with the custom activity any logging needs to be done by the services invoked by ADF. There isn't anything you can add directly into the JSON that would write out to a log file.

It would be nice to have ADF output to the Azure main activity and monitoring logs at all!

I suggest you post this as an idea on the Microsoft user voice pages...

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/

Hope this helps.